# Get Strings with Strtok in C

Tags: c, strtok

I want to split a string to 3 parts.

```
gets(input);

printf("\n%s\n",input);

first = strtok (input, " ");
second = strtok ( NULL, " " );
others = "";
while(input != NULL){
    tmp = strtok ( NULL, " " );
    strcat(others,tmp);
}
```

like this... So i want to get first word, second word into a string and others in a string. This code fails, how can i resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings in C aren't magic, they're *character arrays*. You cannot just `strcat` into a readonly, empty string. Rather, you have to provide your own target string:

```
char others[1000] = { 0 };
char * tmp;

// ...

while ((tmp = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL)
{
  strcat(others, tmp);
}
```

You also used `input` and `tmp` wrong; you should be checking the result of `strtok` before processing it.

This is somewhat dangerous since you have no control over the resulting string length. You should use `strncat` instead, but that means you'll also have to keep count of the appended characters.

Comment: No problem. Please to take a look at `strncat`, though - the use of the unsafe `strcat` is generally frowned upon and essentially unacceptable in any sort of serious code. (Actually, so is `gets()`, for that matter.) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You should be checking

```
while (tmp != NULL)
```

Also, "others" doesn't point to any allocated memory, so I'd expect this to crash until you fix that.

Answer (score 0):

There are several flaws with the code:

Assuming, `others` is a character array, you can't work with it in that manner. You have to allocate sufficient memory.

Also, the condition should be

```
while(tmp != NULL)
```

Also, the statment  `second = strtok ( NULL, " " );` is redundant, you should be doing this inside the loop.